# Como ejecutar correctamente webdriver selenium chrome y firefox?

Tags: java, netbeans, selenium

Hola he estado viendo tutoriales de como ejecutar selenium webdriver en firefox y en chrome pero no me funcionan solo se abre el navegador pero no accede a la pagina que le indico, ya intente de varias formas y no me funciona, estos son mis codigos

firefox 55 linux 64 bits

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "/opt/firefox/firefox");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities); 

    driver.get("https://facebook.com");
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
```

Google Chrome 61 linux 64 bits

```
 public static String driverPath = "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome";
  public static WebDriver driver;

  public Pruebas()
  {
   System.out.println("launching chrome browser");
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
   driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.navigate().to("https://facebook.com");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Pruebas();
  }
```

Solo me abre los navegadores pero no se dirige a la pagina que le indico

google chorme: da error de timeout

firefox: Preferring the firefox binary in these options (/opt/firefox/firefox rather than /opt/firefox/firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas tardes,

lo que sucede es que la version de selenium que tienes no es compatible con la version de tu navegador, intentalo asi:

FIREFOX

```
WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/ruta/geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Descargar el geckodriver de: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

CHROME

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/ruta/chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Descargar el chromedriver de: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Finalmente:

```
driver.get("URL");
```

> NOTA: No dependeras de tus navegadores, simplemente con el geckodriver levanta firefox y con el chromedriver levanta google chrome,

Espero te sirva, saludos

Comment: Nota: nunca tomes la ultima version del geckodriver o chrome driver suelen tener conflictos o problemas, prueba con una mas abajo o dos

Answer (score 1):

Si llega a abrir el navegador pero no interactua con el, lo mas normal es que las versiones entre los navegadores y selenium esten desalineadas.

Para esas versiones que indicas de los navegadores yo utilizaria la version 3.4 de selenium, con gecko driver para firefox en la version [0.18](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) y la ultima de Chrome driver, ahora mismo la [2.32](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de error se produce cuando se agregan los archivos jar externos en el ModulePath. Para resolver este problema, elimina los archivos jar externos del nodo "Modulepath". Selecciona el nodo "Classpath" y luego agrega los frascos externos. Revisa que todos los frascos estén debajo del nodo "Classpath"

Yo tenía exactamente el mismo problema y me estaba rompiendo la cabeza para encontrar la forma de solucionarlo.

Sincero agradecimiento a [@Abha](https://www.edureka.co/community/user/562510) de edureka.co

PD: las otras resupestas están bien, únicamente que no funcionan sin hacer lo que acabo de mencionar.